# Split by delimiter which is contained in a record

Tags: sql, csv, split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, delimiter

I have a column which I am splitting in Snowflake.

The format is as follows:

[image]

I have been using `split_to_table(A, ',')` inside of my query but as you can probably tell this uncorrectly also splits the `Scooter > Sprinting, Jogging and Walking` record.

Perhaps having the delimiter only work if there is no spaced on either side of it? As I cannot see a different condition that could work.

I have been researching online but haven't found a suitable work around yet, is there anyone that encountered a similar problem in the past?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get a little clever with `regexp_replace` by replacing the actual delimiters with something else before the table split. I am using double pipes `'||'` but you can change that to something else. The `'\|\|\\1'` trick is called [back-referencing](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html#:%7E:text=The%20following%20example%20uses%20backreferences%20to%20rearrange%20the%20string) that allows us to include the captured group (`\\1`) as part of replacement (`\|\|`)

```
set str='car>bike,bike>car,truck, and jeep,horse>cat,truck>car,truck, and jeep';

select $str, *
from table(split_to_table(regexp_replace($str,',([^>,]+>)','\|\|\\1'),'||'))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a custom rule for the split to table, so we can use a UDTF to apply a custom rule:

```
create or replace function split_to_table2(STR string, DELIM string, ROW_MUST_CONTAIN string)
returns table (VALUE string)
language javascript
strict immutable
as
$$
{
    initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {
    },
    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
        var buffer = "";
        var i;
        const s = row.STR.split(row.DELIM);
        for(i=0; i<s.length-1; i++) {
            buffer += s[i];
            if(s[i+1].includes(row.ROW_MUST_CONTAIN)) {
                rowWriter.writeRow({VALUE: buffer});
                buffer = "";
            } else {
                buffer += row.DELIM
            }
        }
        rowWriter.writeRow({VALUE: s[i]})
    },
}
$$;

select VALUE from 
table(split_to_table2('Car > Bike,Bike > Scooter,Scooter > Sprinting, Jogging and Walking,Walking > Flying', ',', '>'))
;
```

Output:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| Car > Bike |
| Bike > Scooter |
| Scooter > Sprinting, Jogging and Walking |
| Walking > Flying |

This UDTF adds one more parameter than the two in the build in table function `split_to_table`. The third parameter, ROW_MUST_CONTAIN is the string a row must contain. It splits the string on DELIM, but if it does not have the ROW_MUST_CONTAIN string, it concatenates the strings to form a complete string for a row. In this case we just specify `,` for the delimiter and `>` for ROW_MUST_CONTAIN.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. The only pattern, which I can see, is the one with the whitespace after the comma.

It's a small workaround but we can make use of this pattern. In below code I am replacing such commas, where we do have whitespaces afterwards. Then I am applying split to table function and I am converting the previous replacement back.

It's not super pretty and would crash if your string contains "my_replacement" or any other new pattern, but its working for me:

```
select replace(t.value, 'my_replacement', ', ') 
from table(
           split_to_table(replace('Car > Bike,Bike > Scooter,Scooter > Sprinting, Jogging and Walking,Walking > Flying', ', ', 'my_replacement'),',')) t
```